# How to use shared_ptr to supply mock object from outside?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, shared-ptr

I want to test an app `Thud`, which will use a resource `Foo`. It will not own a concrete object but will have a pointer to a abstract resource interface (`IFoo` here). In production I will supply it with the actual resource implementation (`FooImpl`) whereas for unit test I want to send a pointer to a mock resource. How should I do this ? I've tried to write the least code just to get to point,

```
class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual bool Foo(bool) = 0;
};

class FooImpl : public IFoo
{
public:
    bool Foo(bool b) override
    {
        return b;
    }
};

class FooMock : public IFoo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(Foo, bool(bool));
};

class ThudTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    virtual void SetUp() {
        //foo.reset(&mock); //line#1
        foo = &mock; //line#2
    }

    FooMock mock;
    //std::shared_ptr<IFoo> foo; //line#3
    IFoo* foo; //line#4
};

class Thud
{
    //std::shared_ptr<IFoo> fooPtr; //line#5
    IFoo* fooPtr; //line#6
public:
    /*Thud(std::shared_ptr<IFoo> fooPtr_) : fooPtr{ fooPtr_ }
    {}*/ //line#7
    Thud(IFoo* fooPtr_) : fooPtr{ fooPtr_ }
    {} //line#8
    bool thud1(bool b)
    {
        return fooPtr->Foo(b);
    }
};

TEST_F(ThudTest, fooFalse)
{
    bool b = false;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, Foo(b)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(false));;

    Thud thud(foo);
    EXPECT_FALSE(thud.thud1(b));
}

TEST_F(ThudTest, fooTrue)
{
    bool b = true;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, Foo(b)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(true));;

    Thud thud(foo);
    EXPECT_TRUE(thud.thud1(b));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // The following line must be executed to initialize Google Mock
    // (and Google Test) before running the tests.
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

So for completion I've has an overloaded constructor that takes not arguement but will do the following,

```
Thud():fooPtr {std::make_shared<FooImpl>()}
{}
```

to get the real implementation in production.
But now how do I make the pointer point to the mock object. As you can see, I'm using GMock framework here. How to achieve this ?

If I comment out line #2,4,6 & 8 which uses a plain old raw pointer and uncomment and use line #1,3,5 & 7 (using the `shared_ptr` in question here) instead, it crashes with heap corruption after the first test case.

It works perfectly with this raw pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do `foo.reset(&mock)`, since then `mock` has two owners: its automatic storage duration, plus the shared pointer `foo`. Memory corruption FTW.

You should simply allocate the `FooMock` dynamically and pass it in when creating the `Thud` instance being tested:

```
class ThudTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    virtual void SetUp() {
        foo = std::make_shared<FooMock>();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<FooMock> foo;
};
```

You won't even need the `mock` member any more. Note that I've changed the type of `foo` to know about `FooMock`, so that you can access that type. If you really want `foo` to remain mock-unaware, do it like this:

```
class ThudTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    virtual void SetUp() {
        mock = std::make_shared<FooMock>();
        foo = mock;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<FooMock> mock;
    std::shared_ptr<IFoo> foo;
};
```

However, this should not be necessary, since `std::shared_ptr<FooMock>` is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<IFoo>`.

Comment: Thanks Angew. Yes, I think that is what I need. But, how should do I it exactly ? I'm new to these smart pointers.

Comment: but then, if not for the `mock` object, what object do I pass to my expectation clause here `EXPECT_CALL(mock, Foo(b)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(false));` ? On which object do I set my expectations ?

Comment: You set your expectations on the mock.

Comment: @user3222 The mock object is owned by `ThudTest::foo`, so you can use that to refer to it.

Comment: @robert: That is the point, OP no has the mock object, (or he has to casting it :/)

Comment: @Angew thanks for your help. I did not understand that, I was making the shared_ptr own the local auto, object, causing a corruption, when the scope ends. Thanks for pointing out. I used Jarod42's suggestions as well. It worked indeed! thanks to both of you

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
class Thud
{
    std::shared_ptr<IFoo> fooPtr;
public:
    Thud(std::shared_ptr<IFoo> fooPtr_) : fooPtr{ fooPtr_ }
    {}
    bool thud1(bool b)
    {
        return fooPtr->Foo(b);
    }
};
```

Your tests can become (I remove the Feature):

```
TEST(ThudTest, fooFalse)
{
    auto mock = std::make_shared<FooMock>()
    bool b = false;
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock, Foo(b)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(false));;

    Thud thud(mock);
    EXPECT_FALSE(thud.thud1(b));
}

TEST(ThudTest, fooTrue)
{
    auto mock = std::make_shared<FooMock>()
    bool b = true;
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock, Foo(b)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(true));;

    Thud thud(mock);
    EXPECT_TRUE(thud.thud1(b));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my solution a needed to use `shared_ptr<IFoo>` to add it to collection in other tested class and I figured out to use a referecne ;). Then I tried with `NiceMock<IFoo>` and `StrictMock<IFoo>` also and it worked.

```
using namespace testing;
using namespace std;

class ThudTest : public Test {
  public:
    shared_ptr<FooMock> fooPtr_ = make_shared<FooMock>();
    // shared_ptr<StrictMock<FooMock>> fooPtr_ = make_shared<StrictMock<FooMock>>();
    FooMock& mock = *fooPtr_;
    // StrictMock<FooMock>& mock= *fooPtr_;

    bool thud1(bool b) {
        return fooPtr_->Foo(b);
    }
};
```

And tests can be writen without `*`:

```
TEST_F(ThudTest, fooFalse) {
    bool b = false;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, Foo(b)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(false));

    EXPECT_FALSE(thud1(b));
}

TEST_F(ThudTest, fooTrue) {
    bool b = true;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, Foo(b)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(true));

    EXPECT_TRUE(thud1(b));
}
```